# Dynamically Show Radius Changing on Editable Circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

My Intent is to provide the user with the circle's radius while they are adjusting its radius, via the editable=true option. Currently, I can only display the radius value **after** the radius has been changed. Any Ideas?.
Code shown below:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(MyCircleDraw, 'radius_changed', function(){
  var radius=this.getRadius()/1000; 
  circleDrawRadiusValue.value=radius.toFixed(3)
});
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  Are you listening to the radius_changed event?  Where are you displaying the radius?

Comment: Rather than using editable for the circle, I placed a marker on the circle's northern circumference, dragged it with a fixed longitude, using that to setRadius of the circle.

Comment: If that is your solution/answer to your question, please post it as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).